# Does the photon decay due to loss of energy in a gravitational shock wave that it creates?

Tags: photons, gravitational-waves

If photon has energy, it has gravity.

If photon has gravity and move through space at light speed, it creates gravitational shock wave (like sonic boom because gravity move at the same speed as photon).

If photon creates gravitational shock wave, it looses energy.

If photon looses energy, so it decays.

Which sentence is wrong ? I don't think all of these will be true because if these are true, they will prove that photon have to decay which we still can't prove. But I have no idea which one is wrong.

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335917/20427

Comment: I don't understand very deep physics or I have to understand it if I want to know. Could you just say which one is wrong or can't be prove by law that it doesn't have to be always true ?

Comment: Regarding photon decay in general, as opposed to this mechanism, see Julian Heeck, How stable is the photon?, http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2821

Comment: The photons in a beam of light do not have a well-defined location. In fact, the photon model is generally not useful when you want to describe how light travels. Please see [What's the physical meaning of the statement that "photons don't have positions"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/492711/123208)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If photon has gravity and move through space at light speed, it creates gravitational shock wave (like sonic boom because gravity move at the same speed as photon).

Not true. You're using a mechanical analogy that simply doesn't work here.

Comment: Massless particles (like photons) are, in fact, accompanied by gravitational shock waves. In that sense the OP is correct. However, this shockwave is not created by the photon as it travels (but must be created simulatneously with the emission of the photon). In particular, there is no energy transfer from the photon to the shockwave as the two travel.